# How to set a new shortcut for a button in a popup box of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

[image]
As you can see in the picture, I need to manually check this macro and select `Expand Inline`in the popup box, he's a pain in the ass because I often leave this popup box in the wrong place causing the The popup box disappears, and the only way to prevent it from disappearing is to strictly follow the track of the red line.

Is there a way to set a shortcut to "expand the macro to the cursor position" so that I don't need to use the mouse to do this?